# mount(2) system call failed: Remote I/O error error when mounting exfat external hard drive

Tags: partitioning, external-hdd

I recently got a new external hard drive of a capacity 2 To formatted in exFAT, but I can't use it.

When I try to mount it with `sudo mount /dev/sdc /test`, I get:

```
mount: /test: mount(2) system call failed: Remote I/O error.
```

And `mount -t exfat /dev/sdc1 /test`:

```
FUSE exfat 1.3.0
ERROR: failed to read boot sector.
```

The `sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdc` command outputs:

```
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.8.0-48-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

Read Device Identity failed: scsi error device will be ready soon

A mandatory SMART command failed: exiting. To continue, add one or more '-T permissive' options.
```

`lsblk` outputs this (now HDD is on `/dev/sdb`) :

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0  55,5M  1 loop /snap/core18/1988
loop1    7:1    0  55,4M  1 loop /snap/core18/1944
loop2    7:2    0   219M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/66
loop3    7:3    0    51M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/518
loop4    7:4    0  65,3M  1 loop /snap/powershell/160
loop5    7:5    0  64,8M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1514
loop6    7:6    0  32,3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/11107
loop7    7:7    0  32,3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/11402
sda      8:0    0 119,2G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   499M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0   128M  0 part 
└─sda3   8:3    0 118,6G  0 part 
sdb      8:16   0   1,8T  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   0 976,6G  0 part 
sdc      8:32   1  30,2G  0 disk 
├─sdc1   8:33   1   500M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sdc2   8:34   1    20G  0 part /
└─sdc3   8:35   1   9,8G  0 part /data/on-cle
```

GParted crashes on launch with many error messages, and Disks doesn't even show the device.

Can anybody help me ?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this a 2TB drive? Your mount command is incorrect. See `man mkdir` and `man mount`.

Comment: I think the correct command is sudo mount -t exfat /dev/sdc# /test where # is the partition number. If your disk is previously unused your  issue is elsewhere. It may be faulty. What does lsblk show?